# Conda hangs when installing new Python version

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, python3, anaconda, conda

Some of the output of `conda search python` is:

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
python                         3.9.0 h2a148a8_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 h852b56e_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 h852b56e_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0 h852b56e_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.0      hcff3b4d_1  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.0      hdb3f193_2  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.0 hffdb5ce_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1      hdb3f193_2  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.1 hffdb5ce_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hffdb5ce_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hffdb5ce_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hffdb5ce_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hffdb5ce_4_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.1 hffdb5ce_5_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.2      hdb3f193_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.2 hffdb5ce_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.4      hdb3f193_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.4 hffdb5ce_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.5      h12debd9_4  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.5 h49503c6_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.5      hdb3f193_3  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.6      h12debd9_0  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.6      h12debd9_1  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.6 h49503c6_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.6 h49503c6_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7      h12debd9_1  pkgs/main           
python                         3.9.7 h49503c6_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 hb7a2778_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 hb7a2778_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 hb7a2778_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.7 hf930737_3_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.9 h543edf9_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                         3.9.9 h62f1059_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 h85951f9_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 h85951f9_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 h85951f9_2_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 hc74c709_0_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 hc74c709_1_cpython  conda-forge         
python                        3.9.10 hc74c709_2_cpython  conda-forge
```

When I do `conda install python=3.9 --channel conda-forge` I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
```

It just hangs there. What to do?

Comment: A workaround is to run `conda create --name askubuntu && conda activate askubuntu`

Comment: @Someone is this a serious answer?

Comment: it's a [workaround](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround), it's not the correct way to fix but will fix the issue. You may change `askubuntu` to something of your choice in the command.

Comment: @Someone it worked, thanks. Will leave issue open in case someone wants to state the correct way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work around is to create and activate a new virtual environment for `conda`:

```
conda create --name workaround
conda activate workaround
```

In the above example I used the name `workaround` for the new environment, but you can use any name you wish.